# Unable to connect to neo4j from a docker instance

Tags: node.js, docker, neo4j, bolt

I have a Node.js application that connects to neo4j. Running it normally works well, I'm able to connect. However, when I run it inside Docker I run into this error:

```
Neo4jError: Failed to connect to server. Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0. Caused by: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7687
at newError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/error.js:75:10)
at NodeChannel._handleConnectionError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/internal/node/node-channel.js:229:41)
at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I'm using neo4j-driver v4.0.2, and Neo4j 4.0.3.

I created a repo to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/Layvier/test_neo4j

Am I missing something regarding Docker networking ?

I found this related issue with the python driver: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/issues/251#issuecomment-420160271

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docker image runs in an isolated network so it does not have access to your neo4j at `localhost:7687`

In your javascript file, try changing the url you're connecting to to your host-ip instead of `localhost`. You can find that with running `ip addr show`.

Better yet, you can pass host mappings to your container with the `--add-host` flag - [add host to container example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-entries-to-container-hosts-file---add-host)

```
docker run -it --add-host=neo4j:[your-host-ip] user/test-neo4j:latest
```

You can then connect using `neo4j` instead of `localhost` in your index.js